# Correct CSS Positioning and layout

Tags: javascript, css

### Question

How can i get the `.skillTitle` to sit above the `.chart` and not next to it?

### Code

```
<span class="skillTitle">PHP</span>
 <div class="chart" data-percent="80">
  <span class="percent">80%</span></div>
```

### Preview

```js
$(function() {
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
 easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    barColor: '#207cca',
 trackColor: '#f2f2f2',
 scaleColor: false,
 lineCap: 'square',
 lineWidth: '10'
    });
});
```

```css
.chart {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
   
    margin-bottom: 50px;
 margin-left:10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.chart canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.percent {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 110px;
    z-index: 2;
}


.skillTitle {
 
   position:relative;
   
    z-index: 2;
 font-weight:bold;
 
 
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-pie-chart/2.1.4/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>

<span class="skillTitle">HTML</span>
  <div class="chart" data-percent="73"> 
  <span class="percent">73%</span></div>
  
  <span class="skillTitle">PHP</span>
  <div class="chart" data-percent="80">
  <span class="percent">80%</span></div>
```

Comment: spans are inline divs are blocks. Change css of skillTitle to display:block or change it to a div

Comment: Change .chart to be display:block

Comment: p.s. the issue with your snippet was the Pie Chart library being loaded *before* jQuery. I just swapped them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the titles displayed above each chart, but still have the charts side-by-side, you want to wrap the pairs in a container, and also set `display: block` on `.skillTitle`:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
 easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    barColor: '#207cca',
 trackColor: '#f2f2f2',
 scaleColor: false,
 lineCap: 'square',
 lineWidth: '10'
    });
});
```

```css
.skillTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.ctr {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.chart {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
   
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left:10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.chart canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.percent {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 110px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-pie-chart/2.1.4/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>

<div class="ctr">
  <span class="skillTitle">HTML</span>
    <div class="chart" data-percent="73"> 
    <span class="percent">73%</span></div>
</div>
  
<div class="ctr">
  <span class="skillTitle">PHP</span>
  <div class="chart" data-percent="80">
  <span class="percent">80%</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use block-level element for the chart title, e.g. `<p>` or `<div>`. Because you've used a `<span>`, which is an inline element, and set the following `<div>` element to display as an inline block, the two elements display side by side.

To fix:

HTML:

```
<p class="skillTitle">PHP</p>
<div class="chart" data-percent="80">
  <span class="percent">80%</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.skillTitle {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

No need to use the `position:relative` or `z-index` unless they are specifically required.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8tx1cco/)